# Getting ignoring symlink error in VSCode

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, visual-studio-code, golang, vscode-extensions

I am new to the Golang and VSCode. In my code, I have golang repo having imports from other directories. So, there is a vendor directory of which I am creating a symbolic link in my repo. But all the imports are giving error and are shown in red, and the error is "Error loading workspace: err: exit status 1: stderr: warning: ignoring symlink". Please help me out. I even tried unlinking and linking it again.